# NativeScript : Unable to locate a workspace file for workspace path

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-cli

I'm working on a fresh NativeScript - Angular project and I tried to use angular generators(schematics) using command line. the command I used

```
tns generate component <component name>
```

it results me,

```
Error: Unable to locate a workspace file for workspace path.
at Object.readWorkspace (C:\Users\REDTECH\Desktop\NativeScript\attendence-manager-mobile\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\core.js:75:19)
at async Object.getWorkspace (C:\Users\REDTECH\Desktop\NativeScript\attendence-manager-mobile\node_modules\@schematics\angular\utility\workspace.js:53:27)
```

I also tried to use

```
ng g c <component name>
```

and it results me

```
The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
```

I tried re-installing angular cli, nativescript cli and @nativescript/schematics but it didnt fixed the problum.

Comment: not sure what suddenly happened to NativeScript, but this happens to me, this is due to a missing `angular.json` file, but according to NativeScript - we don't need such anymore ... so i'm not sure what's going on

Comment: Also i wonder if the project ever worked for you ? https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/2247

Answer (score 0):

ng is for angular, ns is for nativescript, try ns g c  or even better, ns generate component